What is the optimum lunar latitude for a solar farm and hydrolysis plant?
What is the optimum lunar latitude for a solar farm and hydrolysis plant?
Water is hypothesized to be present at the lunar poles. There have been proposals to hydrolyzed it into propellant. Large amounts of electrical power will be needed at the location of the hydrolysis plant. Solar panels are a leading contender for this job, along with nuclear and solar thermal https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20100017257/downloads/20100017257.pdf
However, the optimum location for solar farms is not at the latitude of the hypothesized water. Should the electricity be transmitted to the water or the water to the solar farm? At what latitude should they be located?
High latitude solar farms require a large pitch distance (the distance between rows of panels) to avoid one panel row from shading the next.

High latitude

Low latitude
The pitch distance increases with the tangent of the latitude https://azsolarcenter.org/pv-row-to-row-spacing , so farm area increases dramatically near the poles. Low panel density increases the cost of structural supports and conductors.

How to bring the water together with the electricity? Power can be transmitted long distances with high voltage DC current, but this requires significant infrastructure. Transporting water equivalent lunar distances would be a challenge.

The optimum solution depends on the latitude of the solar farm(s) and their number, since 24/7 hydrolysis would require multiple farms.
This discussion ignores the fact that propellant needs to eventually be at the same location as the rocket which needs a fill-up.
As early as 1837, it was suggested  there may exist a “peak of eternal light”  at high latitude on mountainous astronomic bodies such as the moon. It has been suggested solar panels could be located at these "points of perpetual sunlight".
According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_of_eternal_light

Detailed lunar topography collected by the Lunar Reconnaissance
Orbiter (LRO) suggests that no points on the Moon receive perpetual
light during both the winter and summer… there are points on crater
rims which have very extended periods of sunlight.
The lunar south pole is situated in a huge depression, … Careful
analysis of imagery and topographic conditions on the lunar South Pole
by teams from NASA and the ESA revealed a small number of illuminated
ridges within 15 km of the pole, each of them much like an island of
no more than a few hundred meters across in an ocean of eternal
darkness, where a lander could receive near-permanent lighting (for
~70–90% of the southern lunar winter, and likely all of the southern
lunar summer)

Electrolysis of water is energy intensive and requires very large solar arrays to provide the necessary 286kJ/mole of water. To fill the equivalent of a Saturn V second stage (total 306,000kg propellant) in a day would require 366,000m^2 of panels if the panels were located on Earth with 12 hour days. This would require a wall 10m high and 36,600 meters long. There are 4 peaks near the lunar South Pole which are illuminated more than 80% of the time, so the equivalent lunar installation may get away with only 22 km of panels. However, the peaks in question are 2 orders of magnitude too small. And the tangent formula for panel spacing still applies, even for rotating panels, since rotating panels can shade their neighbors as effectively as fixed panels.
Long distance power transmission on the moon using high voltage DC does not necessarily require large conductors or unacceptable transmission loss. Mass of a circumlunar power transmission line?
Lunar power transmission using bare conductors laying on the regolith?

Just estimating, but I'd say there is almost no case for bringing things to the power source. While setting up long-distance power transmission infrastructure is not easy, setting up a logistical network to transfer bulk materials is orders of magnitude more difficult than spanning a couple wires. Consider that aluminum wiring could be manufactured in-situ, and there are other advantages that make long over"land" runs easier on the moon (vacuum, low temperature, no pesky property owners, etc)

Additionally, consider that a cable run from the equator to one of the poles would "only" be about 2500 km, and using HVDC overland has about 2%-3% loss per 100km, so this run would have losses of around 50%. That's not good, but this is essentially the maximum run.

In terms of solar panel location, I think it will be very hard to argue against putting them in an "eternal sun" spot at eg. the south pole. Otherwise, creating a system which delivers high power through the very long lunar night will be a significant challenge as the panel count would essentially need to be doubled to provide not only the base load but also fill any grid storage accumulators.

For the actual mechanical solution of mounting panels, the Moon opens up a new engineering space: with the very low gravity and absence of wind, we could build very tall lightweight truss structures that hold large "sails" of solar panels at essentially 90°. These would be built at the south pole, and have the ability to rotate so they always face the energy source, like windmills can here on Earth.

This paper has a fantastic analysis of generating solar power at the south pole: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576523003399 Unfortunately, it's paid, so you'll need to get access from somewhere.

Keeping the temperature of the transmission lines within operational limits will be a big issue since there is no air to cool them. May need to bury the conductors, leading to greater difficulty.

Rhetorical question: What's better, to create a solar array at the equator (where the sun only shines 50% of the time) and run 2500 km long cables to the south pole, transport material over rough lunar terrain for 2500 km, or build your solar farm near the south pole and perhaps have to run cables a few hundred extra meters longer due to the need to separate the arrays? It's not as if there isn't a lot of acreage there.

@JonCuster that shouldn't be too much of a problem. Just make the lines in a flat ribbon form - lots of surface area to radiate heat from, which it readily will as soon as the temperature rises. What I'd rather be concerned about is electrostatically charged dust; I don't what would happen with that.


However, the optimum location for solar farms is not at the latitude of the hypothesized water.

It most certainly is, assuming the solar arrays are orientable. There are places near the Moon's south pole that are perpetually lit by sunlight. There is no such thing as atmospheric absorption of sunlight on the Moon. There is essentially no atmosphere on the Moon, so zero air mass. Air mass is a problem with regard to solar arrays on the Earth, but is a non-problem on the Moon.
Assuming the solar arrays can always remain oriented so their normals always remain orthogonal to the incoming sunlight, the best place for a lunar solar array is those perpetually sunlit places near the Moon's south pole. Added advantage: there are other places near the Moon's south pole that are perpetually in shadow. Those perpetually shadowed craters are where water ice exist.

see edited OP. The south pole areas that are "perpetually" lit have too small an area to provide solar panel power for an industrial scale hydrolysis plant. They could be very useful for lower power applications like recharging rovers or powering a habitation.

@Woody -- We are not going to be doing "industrial scale" work on the Moon for decades, which would make your question (a) science fiction, and (b) more suitable to the WorldBuilding StackExchange rather than here. (Aside: I am not a fan of science fiction questions at this site. Others however are.)

As an additional aside, once we humans do get to the stage of "industrial scale hydrolysis", that use of a very limited resource may well be verboten. The water will be needed as water for crops and animals (including humans). Sending it into space is kinda silly. Water on the Moon is a very limited and rather precious resource, and it is absolutely essential for life as we know it.
